# jQuery addClass() followed by accessing width returns wrong value

Tags: jquery, css

I'm getting inconsistent return values when accessing width after adding an "active" class on a selection (4 items). I have a horizontal slider that needs to know the widths of its elements, which changes because the "active" one employs a bold font, thus changing the size of the element slightly.

The problem is, if I add the "active" class and immediately request the width, it returns the old value. I confirmed this by changing the class, logging all widths, and then placing a timeout of 50ms and logging all widths again immediately after. The values change, as you can see below (note, its in an angular app, thus the usage of $timeout):

```
pageNavButtons.addClass("active");
pageNavButtons.each(function () {
    console.log(Math.ceil($(this).get(0).getBoundingClientRect().width));
});

$timeout(function(){
    pageNavButtons.each(function ({
        console.log(Math.ceil($(this).get(0).getBoundingClientRect().width));
    });
},50);
```

You'd expect to see the same widths logged two times. But you don't, you instead get this:

```
207
217
196
176

207
220
200
179
```

This consistently reproduces. I have a feeling the renderer is still working, but how can I force it to wait? window.requestAnimationFrame is not working, and I don't want to use a timer, thats a sloppy hack.

Note I'm using getBoundingClientRect because of the bug in jQuery that rounds down for outerWidth(), and I need the sub-pixel precision.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean by :

```
$timeout(function(){....
```

maybe you want to use this:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    pageNavButtons.each(function ({
     console.log(Math.ceil($(this).get(0).getBoundingClientRect().width));
});
```

}, 2000);

This will pause the execution of the inner script;

Comment: Quoted from my original message: (note, its in an angular app, thus the usage of $timeout) -- $timeout is Angular's window.settimeout which improves testability. Call them identical for all intents and purposes.

Comment: Also, my entire question is about AVOIDING the usage of timeouts. Using a timeout is a guess at how long the render will take, and is therefore a hack and succeptable to breakage.